# how to define tagsAllowed options of StripTags in ini file as array in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

**I have few tags to be allowed those should declared in ini file as array**

I have tried following:

> comment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed = iframe

It is working

But when using array like this:

> frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed[] = div
>   frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed[] = iframe

It's not working

It's really paining me ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.one = div
frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.two = iframe
frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.three = other
```

Works for you? :)

Comment: **Not working** `frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.one = b
frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.two = i
frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed.three = ul`                                      But it's working single `frontendcomment.elements.comment_desc.options.filters.StripTags.options.tagsAllowed = b`